# Google Tag Manager with GA

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want your help

I am working on GTM. I have issue with product category in "eCommerce > Product performance." tab.

I send data from dataLayer like following.

```
dataLayer.push({
           'event': 'PlaceOrder',
           'ecommerce': {
               'purchase': {
                   'actionField': {
                       'id': 'T12359',                       
                       'affiliation': 'Online Store',
                       'revenue': '55.43',                    
                       'tax': '4.20',
                       'shipping': '6.69'
                   },
                   'products': [{                     
                       'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt test',
                       'id': 'test_0_1_0',
                       'price': '15.25',
                       'category': 'Apparel',
                       'quantity': 1
                   }, {
                       'name': 'Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt test',
                       'id': 'test_0_2_0',
                       'price': '33.75',
                       'category': 'Apparel',
                       'quantity': 3
                   }]
               }
           }
       });
```

but i cant see any details ( ie. "category: Apparel").
please check this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0uzJ.png).

Thanking You in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8Je7.png)

Comment: Add secondary dimension in the report  `product category`. You will see them.

Comment: Can you install the GA debugger Chrome extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) and copy and paste the output of this extension (which you can find in the developer tools > console tab) after a transaction is complete?

Comment: The code looks fine. Did you wait 24-48 hours for the data to be processed? Also, as @faridghar suggested, use GA Debugger or Chrome dev tools to make sure your transaction hit has the `category`. Also, make sure your tag is firing, presumable on the `PlaceOrder` event(?).

Comment: yes tushar, i tryed your mention process, but still not seen any deatils. on primary dimension tab, product & SKU section shows correct product name & SKU, but category still not anythings.

Comment: @nyuen & @ faridghar, i using google tag manager's "Preview and Debug" option. and my trigger also fires my tag thats why transaction, SKU, product name seen, only category issue i have, please help. Thank You.

Comment: Can you send screenshots of the following 1) Your dataLayer as shown in the developer tools console 2) A screenshot of the console output of the GA debugger chrome extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**issue solved.**

just turn on following option.

Analytics > view > eCommerce setting >

1) Ecommerce set-up >
     status: ON.
     related products: ON.

2) Enhanced eCommerce Settings(Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Reporting).

---

2nd option is important, that was remaining to turn ON.

**Thank you all to respond me quickly.**